# Not generating Jacoco report for android libs with Gradle wrapper 6.5.1 in android project?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, code-coverage, jacoco, gradlew

I have created a simple android project to demonstrate the issue.
After updating **gradle-wrapper** for the android project, Jacoco does not consider unit tests coverage for android libs.

Current versions:
classpath "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.6"
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:3.1.1"

Following are the Jacoco Reports for gradle wrapper **6.5.1**
[Project Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIq2M.png)
[App Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMThP.png)
[Lib Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTYWn.png)

Same project reporting 100% code coverage for gradle wrapper 6.3.
I don't want to update my wrapper version to 6.3 in my actual project due to technical requirements.

Sample Repo - https://github.com/Gaurav-Sutar/JacocoReport/tree/master

Comment: I got a temporary solution by using "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.9" for now. It is perfectly working with the newer Gradle wrapper for me.

Comment: The same issue with the latest Jacoco 0.8.7 and the latest grade wrapper 6.7.1. ETA?